# Finding app config file from assembly

Tags: c#, config

I'm using [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/) to read config throughout the app. I'm running into a problem in assemblies where I want to read the main applications config file (regardless of web.config or app.config).

This is standard way:

`private static IConfigSource source = new DotNetConfigSource(DotNetConfigSource.GetFullConfigPath());`

The problem in the case of assemblies is that `DotNetConfigSource.GetFullConfigPath()` returns "assembly.dll.config", not "app.exe.config" or "web.config".

What to do, what to do?

Comment: Are you restricted by Nini? Could you use System's ConfigurationManager class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
                ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

string configPath = config.FilePath;

private static IConfigSource source = new DotNetConfigSource(configPath);
```

Try that.